# Picking 1 action out of multiple continous actions

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Im trying to implement an environment where you have multiple dials which can be turned from 0-100. Only 1 dial can be turned at each step. So far i did it with a discrete actionspace giving 100 action for each dial, so the agent would pick a dial and a position. 
I would like to convert it to continous actionspace. To do so i took a look at the implementation of a2c for BipedalWalker-v2. The problem i am facing now is that these implementations return an action for each actuator. In my case the agent is only allowed to choose 1 actuator and turn it from 0-100. What would be the optimal approach to do so?

Comment: From what I understand of your question, I would use a random.randint(0, 100) and just have an if statement for each of the possible integers. Or, if each one is similar, make a function that does something based off of an imputed number (the random integer).

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me i was searching for a possibility to do this with the help of a neural network. Hence the reinforcement-learning tag

Comment: I see. I have no experience with neural networks, so I cannot help you. :(